# Oracle SQL Query

Tags: oracle

Query the two cities in STATION (Table) with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

can any one know how to solve such type of question in sql

Comment: Output may be like this  ABC 3
PQRS 4

Comment: This seems like homework,so I`ll only give you a hint: LENGTH

Comment: Have you tried to research how to do this or have you made attempts that have not worked as required yourself ? If so then you should include this in the post.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i tried like this                                                                                                                                                                                                        2   select city,length(city) from station
where length(city) = (select max(length(city))  from station) 
or  length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from station );                                      and get the output like this                                                                                                     Roy 3 
Amo 3 
Marine On Saint Croix 21 
Lee 3

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? It's just your comment query with a little bit added

```
SELECT city_name, length(city_name) 
FROM station 
WHERE LENGTH(city_name) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(city_name)) FROM station) 
OR    LENGTH(city_name) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(city_name)) FROM station )
ORDER BY (city_name) DESC, city_name;
```

This was done on a MySQL instance, but if this doesn't do what you require, please clarify your requirements.

### Test data used:

```
CREATE TABLE station (city_name VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('Seoul');
INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('Roma');
INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('Paris');
INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('Cork');
INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('Adelaide');
INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('Belfast');
INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('London');
INSERT INTO station (city_name) VALUES('Sydney');
```

### Result:

```
city_name  length(city_name)
--------   ----------------
Adelaide                  8
Cork                      4
Roma                      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select city_name
from (
    select city_name
      , row_number() over (order by length(city_name) asc, city_name) as rn1
      , row_number() over (order by length(city_name) desc, city_name) as rn2
    from station
) as T
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1
```

The idea is to create an order number based on smallest length and in case of a tie, city_name (rn1). We also create an order number based on biggest length and in case of a tie, city_name (rn2). From there we can choose the rows that qualifies first according to those two orderings.